# Get all orders shipped to NY

Tags: mysql, sql, select

`orders` table has a `billing_state` filed and a `shipping_state` field. I need to get orders which were shipped to NY state. Suppose an order was billed and shipped to NY state. In this case `billing_state` field has value NY and ship_state is `null`. One order was placed from CA and shipped to NY. `billing_state` value is CA and `shipping_state` is NY.

Now what should be the query to get both rows in result?

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE dateord>='2014-02-25' 
AND dateord<='2014-02-25' 
AND activeFlag=1 
AND (ship_state='NY' 
     OR (billing_state = 'NY' AND ship_state='')) 
order by ordId
```

Comment: `dateord>='2014-02-25' AND dateord<='2014-02-25' ` doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: To be more specific, this is the same as saying `dateord = '2014-02-25'`

Comment: I pasted dynamic generated query here. Most of the time date range is more than one day. In that case it's required in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ship_state` is NULL, comparing it against an empty string won't generate a match. If `dateord` is a timestamp, *i.e.*, it includes the time portion, you will also need to modify the date filter.

Try the following WHERE statement if `ship_state` is NULL and `dateord` is a timestamp.

```
WHERE (dateord >= '2014-02-25')
  AND (dateord < '2014-02-25' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND (activeFlag = 1)
  AND (COALESCE(`ship_state`, `billing_state`) = 'NY')
```

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there,

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE dateord>='2014-02-25' 
AND dateord<='2014-02-25' 
AND activeFlag=1 
AND (ship_state='NY' 
     OR (billing_state = 'NY' AND ship_state IS NULL)) 
order by ordId
```

With most DBMSs (Oracle being an exception, MySQL being included) `''` and `NULL` are different values.

You might want to re-check the validation

```
WHERE dateord>='2014-02-25' AND dateord<='2014-02-25'
```

As it is the same of saying

```
WHERE dateord = '2015-02-25'
```

Comment: I'd clarify that to *With most DBMSs (Oracle being an exception)* if it were me. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite It's always better to clarify :) Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Nice remark, yet I would not encourage anybody to use that peculiar behavior.

Comment: @KenWhite I think he does not encourage the behaviour of comparing with '' using Oracle, not your comment ;)

Comment: Ah, so you think he meant *Oracle's peculiar behavior* and not mine. That makes more sense. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry if I di not express myself properly. Take a deep breath and smile. I meant that Oracle has a peculiar behavior, not you. :-)

Comment: @Tarik: I was already smiling, and I'm breathing just fine. :-) I was just asking you to clarify, and as you can see we've already figured it out (and the request for clarification has already been deleted). :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Null` and `''` are different things. If it's an actual `null`, you need to use the `is` operator:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     orders 
WHERE    dateord >= '2014-02-25' AND 
         dateord <= '2014-02-25' AND 
         activeFlag = 1 AND 
         (ship_state='NY' OR 
          (billing_state = 'NY' AND ship_state IS NULL)) 
ORDER BY ordId
```

Comment: Getting zero rows. 
Well, in first case ship_state field is empty. no value in it. ='' and is NULL both not working

Answer (score 0):

You should use `is null` instead of `= ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Union clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE dateord>='2014-02-25' 
AND dateord<='2014-02-25' 
AND activeFlag=1 
AND ship_state='NY'
order by ordId

union all

SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE dateord>='2014-02-25' 
AND dateord<='2014-02-25' 
AND activeFlag=1 
AND ship_state is null
AND billing_state = 'NY'
order by ordId
```

Comment: order by clause is generating error here. After removing "order by" clause still zero rows. There should be 2 rows in result.

Comment: remove order by clause and replace ship_state = '' to ship_state is null